# How to troubleshoot startup of Android emulator from inside Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, andmore

I have defined an AVD using the Android SDK AVD Manager application.  When I press the "start" button in AVD Manager, it starts correctly.

In Eclipse, I have the "andmore" android tool set installed.  It has a list of available devices that shows the AVD I defined, so clearly it is checking the right place to find them.  The links from the Eclipse menus to open the SDK and AVD manager applications work, so the paths are clearly set up correctly.

Yet, when the AVD is running, Eclipse doesn't realise it: it states it is "offline" and refuses to attempt to install any  applications on it.  And if I stop it and try to start it via the Eclipse UI, it says that it is starting, then immediately stops with the error message "The Android emulator process has unexpectedly stopped running. The instance mm800 is now stopped."

I cannot find any information in the Eclipse error log about why the emulator may have stopped.  Nothing appears in the console window, either.  Where can I find information about what is going wrong?  How can I debug this problem?

For reference:

- Eclipse neon (4.6.0)
- Andmore 0.5.0
- Android SDK Tools 25.1.7
- Android SDK Platform tools 24.0.2
- HAXM 6.0.3
- The AVD I'm trying to use is using the Android 6.0 Google APIs x86 image.

Comment: @World is moving to Android Studio and you are still struck to Eclipse !! go catch the fast moving world

Comment: @dex - Unfortunately, Android Studio isn't very useful for working on projects where I'm sharing components between an android app and a web service.

Answer (score 0):

Did you lately upgrade your eclipse from let's say Indigo to Neon. I had this error happen to me when I did the upgrade. I copied the old Indigo workspace to a new location and then opened it with Neon (didn't create a fresh workspace and import). My AVD did appear offline in device manager view. But when I opened the "Devices" view it appeared okay. 
If you right click your project and go to "Run as" you might find two "Android Application" entries. One with a green icon and another without. Try running it using the **not green** icon. This worked with me. 
Or otherwise try creating a fresh workspace and importing your project into it.
Hope this helps

Edit: I fiddled with it more and created a new workspace. Looks like it does the same as mentioned before. Looks like a problem with the ADT plugin. But still I can run my projects using the "run as android application"

Comment: No, I was using a fresh install of Neon, not an upgrade.  I still don't know what was going wrong -- I stopped trying to use the emulator and just purchased a real Android 6 device for testing purposes...